# Meshes imported to Unreal Engine do not show textures correctly, look like they are shadowed

Tags: materials, uv, normals, unreal-engine

After importing a model to Unreal Engine 5, the textures seem to be shadowed.

I have checked the normals via  the normal viewer and they all seem to be the correct way.

.blend: [image]
[image: Normal Model]
[image: Model in Unreal Engine]
[image: Normal map of Model]

Comment: If you believe you answered your own question then post the solution as an answer and mark that answer as the solution. This will remove the post from the "Unanswered Questions" tab and also help people in the future who might stumble across this post while googling a similar problem.

Comment: @Jakemoyo I am unable to accept my own answer as the correct answer for another 18 hours. I assume this is to discourage people from farming reputation.

Comment: No worries, just know that's the standard procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> and selecting *Apply > Scale* to reset the scale and then re-importing fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just go into Unreal Engine locate the modeling mode in Upbar
scroll down click on normals and flip normals